# deploy de backend de springboot en Render

Tags: spring-boot, deployment

Estoy tratando de hacer el deploy de mi backend hecho con springboot y java. Funciona correctamente en mi computadora pero al tratar de subirlo a Render primero parece que va todo bien:

```
Mar 15 07:10:44 PM  Pushing image to registry...
Mar 15 07:10:48 PM  Upload succeeded
Mar 15 07:10:48 PM  DONE
```

Pero cuando comienza a correr me sale el sigiente error:

```
Mar 15 06:41:32 PM  2023-03-15 21:41:32.773  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1226, SQLState: 42000
Mar 15 06:41:32 PM  2023-03-15 21:41:32.773 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : User 'u3klowhibn0kklay' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 5)
```

y luegode varias líneas me duevuelve: deploy failed.
Necesito su ayuda. Es para presentar el trabajo el 23. :'(

Answer (score 1):

Les cuento: Solo se trataba de matar todas las conexiones a la base de datos en Clever Cloud. No solo una, si no, hasta que funcione. A mi me sirvió resetear la BD y borrar el Web service de Render para hacerlo desde el principio desde 0. Espero que esto le ahorre horas de búsqueda y roturas de cabeza. Saludos